# MOD REWRITE working in local host but not in server

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

First of all , I clarified with my hosting company and they have verified that Allow Override setting is enabled.

Second if I write garbage value in .htaccess file, then I get "Internal Server Error" which further proves that .htaccess is not skipped.

I am trying to do this
Input : all/3
output: all.php?id=3

I wrote following in .htaccess file, which I copied from a tutorial site.

```
# Enable Rewriting  
RewriteEngine on  
# Rewrite user URLs  
#   Input:  user/NAME/  
#   Output: user.php?id=NAME  
RewriteRule ^all/(\w+)/?$ all.php?id=$1
```

all.php file

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Now if I enter `localhost/all/3` then I get 3 displayed.

If i enter `www.mydomain.com/all/3` then the page is blank.

Also I have only the above code in .htaccess file and nothing more or less. So why I am getting different behaviour in localhost and in my server?

Comment: 1. check apache error log 2. check if `.htaccess` is even parsed

Comment: I checked log and following is written "GET /all/3 HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17"

Comment: My localhost is WAMP and the server is linux based...but that should not make the difference, right?

Comment: Add this at the top of `all.php` to see the server variables: `<?php echo var_dump($_SERVER) . "<br /><br />";  ?>` Check `REQUEST_URI`, it should be `/all/3/`.

Comment: it is /all/3 and not /all/3/ ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(6) "/all/3", is it error?

Comment: Hi faa, if I write RewriteRule ^all(\w+)?$ all.php?id=$1, and type www.mydomain.com/all3 [yes all3 only not all/3] then 3 is displayed....

Comment: @DimplePatel Your second comment looks like it's from `access_log`, not `error_log`. You should also enable PHP error reporting, just in case. Put this at the top of your script `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Also, this works fine on my Linux host

Comment: One more thing, your host needs to set `AllowOverride FileInfo` at the minimum for your document root. `AllowOverride all` would also work

Comment: @phil I am not getting any errors. And I am getting strange behaviour. Like when I put **RewriteRule ^all(.*)?$ all.php?id=$1** I get query string as ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(9) "id=.php/3" , so is it some regex matching problem?

Comment: Yes it was some matching problem only. I wrote **^all.php(.*)?$ all.php?id=$1** I get 3 as output!

Comment: Did you add `RewriteBase /` @dimple-patel

Comment: Yup i wrote it afterwards , but it didnt make any difference....it was linking all href like _all/3/logo.png_ as if all and 3 are folders, so I just put '/' in front of all href link like `<a href="/logo.png">`  instead of `<a href="logo.png">`

Comment: Ah, disable `MultiViews`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
RewriteRule ^all/(.*)$ all.php?id=$1
```

Comment: I had tried this, but it takes query string as .php?3 so I used ^all.php/(.*)$, which now skips .php from query string...and now problem is I have to link logo by doing <img src="../../logo.png"> and css as if logo.png is two folders inside, but in reality it is in public folder only.

Comment: gotcha! it was thinking the layout as subpath , So i just added /logo.png which does not match in regex and so now it fetches as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your host has enabled the [`MultiViews` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Solutions are to get them to disable it or probably a quicker option, rename your PHP file to be something other than `all.php`, just so long as the basename (minus the extension) does not match your `RewriteRule` pattern.